# Copy all matching rows into one cell in another table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I'm trying to do is to find all matching IDs from two tables then combine multiple rows into one cell in the original table.

So I have these two tables.
Table 1

```
+-----+-------+
| id  | BS_ID |
+-----+-------+
| 999 | 12345 |
| 977 | 12347 |
| 955 | 12349 |
| 933 | 12351 |
+-----+-------+
```

Table 2

```
+-----+-------+------------+
| id  | BS_ID | callstatus |
+-----+-------+------------+
| 999 | 12345 | noanswer   |
| 999 | 12345 | contacted  |
| 977 | 12347 | noanswer   |
| 955 | 12349 | noanswer   |
| 933 | 12351 | noanswer   |
| 933 | 12351 | contacted  |
+-----+-------+------------+
```

What I want to happen is find all matching rows in table 2 based on the id in table 1. Then copy the "callstatus" in all the matching rows and put it in one cell in table 1 like the one below:

```
+-----+-------+---------------------+
| id  | BS_ID |     callstatus      |
+-----+-------+---------------------+
| 999 | 12345 | noanswer, contacted |
| 977 | 12347 | noanswer            |
| 955 | 12349 | noanswer            |
| 933 | 12351 | noanswer, contacted |
```

I have so far figured out how to count the instances in table 2 but I am stumped on how to copy the "callstatus" into that one cell in table 1.

```
SELECT table1.*
, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM table2 
   WHERE table2.id = table1.id) AS TOT 
FROM table1
```

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause doesn't sound right. You need to mention `WHERE` what `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks @Raj I removed the where clause.. unnecessary. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are:

(But keep in mind: You have no sort order, so the callstatus could appear in random order. And - if you don't need this just for output - think about the possibility to put this in an XML column)

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(id INT,BS_ID INT);
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES
 (999,12345)
,(977,12347)
,(955,12349)
,(933,12351);

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE(id INT,BS_ID INT,callstatus VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES
 (999,12345,'noanswer')
,(999,12345,'contacted')
,(977,12347,'noanswer')
,(955,12349,'noanswer')
,(933,12351,'noanswer')
,(933,12351,'contacted');


SELECT DISTINCT tbl1.id
               ,tbl1.BS_ID
               ,STUFF(
                        (
                        SELECT ', ' + tbl2.callstatus
                        FROM @Table2 AS tbl2
                        WHERE tbl1.id  = tbl2.id AND tbl1.BS_ID=tbl2.BS_ID
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 2, '')  AS StatusList
FROM @Table1 AS tbl1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.id_bsid,substring(statussummary1,1,len(statussummary1)-1)
from table1 t1
       inner join table2 as t21 on t1.id=t21.id and t1.id_bsid=t21.id_bsid
cross apply
(
    SELECT statussummary + ','
    FROM table2 AS t2
    WHERE t2.id = t21.id and t2.id_bsid = t21.id_bsid
    FOR XML PATH('')
)grping(statussummary1)
group by t1.id,t1.id_bsid,statussummary1
```

Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18fb53

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  ;WITH CTE AS
    (
    SELECT
     DetailsTable.id
    ,DetailsTable.BS_ID
    ,(SELECT
        Concated.CALLSTATUS+ ','    
     FROM
        Table2  Concated
    WHERE Concated.id = DetailsTable.id

     FOR XML PATH('')

    )  As callstatus
    FROM
    Table1
    INNER JOIN
    Table2 DetailsTable
    ON Table1.id = DetailsTable.id
    )
    SELECT
      id
     ,BS_ID
     ,SUBSTRING(callstatus,0,LEN(callstatus)) AS CallStatus
    FROM 
    CTE
    GROUP BY
    callstatus
    ,id
    ,BS_ID
    Order by
    id desc
```